# JS radio player keeps resetting while navigating the website

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am using a JS radio player on a website. Anytime someone goes to a new page or refreshes the current page the volume slider resets to 25%. Also, Every time someone goes to a new page the radio player restarts itself causing a break in the music. What would be the best way to fix these issues so that it remembers the users volume and the music doesn't break upon switching pages? I currently have the initial volume set to 25% on load up because it is extremely loud for some reason.

--EDIT--
My question about volume has been answered, now I just need a solution for keeping the player from restarting while switching pages.

Radio Player JS:

```
'use strict';
var audioPlayer = document.querySelector('.ggr-radio-player');
var playPause = audioPlayer.querySelector('#playPause');
var playpauseBtn = audioPlayer.querySelector('.play-pause-btn');
var loading = audioPlayer.querySelector('.loading');
var progress = audioPlayer.querySelector('.ggr-progress');
var sliders = audioPlayer.querySelectorAll('.ggr-slider');
var volumeBtn = audioPlayer.querySelector('.ggr-volume-btn');
var volumeControls = audioPlayer.querySelector('.ggr-volume-controls');
var volumeProgress = volumeControls.querySelector('.ggr-slider .ggr-progress');
var player = audioPlayer.querySelector('audio');
var currentTime = audioPlayer.querySelector('.current-time');
var totalTime = audioPlayer.querySelector('.total-time');
var speaker = audioPlayer.querySelector('#speaker');
var draggableClasses = ['pin'];
var currentlyDragged = null;
player.volume = 0.25;
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    if (!isDraggable(event.target)) return false;
    currentlyDragged = event.target;
    var handleMethod = currentlyDragged.dataset.method;
    this.addEventListener('mousemove', window[handleMethod], false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        currentlyDragged = false;
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', window[handleMethod], false);
    }, false);
});
playpauseBtn.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
player.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress);
player.addEventListener('volumechange', updateVolume);
player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
    totalTime.textContent = formatTime(player.duration);
});
player.addEventListener('canplay', makePlay);
player.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    playPause.attributes.d.value = "M18 12L0 24V0";
    player.currentTime = 0;
});
volumeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    volumeBtn.classList.toggle('open');
    volumeControls.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
window.addEventListener('resize', directionAware);
sliders.forEach(function (slider) {
    var pin = slider.querySelector('.pin');
    slider.addEventListener('click', window[pin.dataset.method]);
});
directionAware();

function isDraggable(el) {
    var canDrag = false;
    var classes = Array.from(el.classList);
    draggableClasses.forEach(function (draggable) {
        if (classes.indexOf(draggable) !== -1) canDrag = true;
    });
    return canDrag;
}

function inRange(event) {
    var rangeBox = getRangeBox(event);
    var rect = rangeBox.getBoundingClientRect();
    var direction = rangeBox.dataset.direction;
    if (direction == 'horizontal') {
        var min = rangeBox.offsetLeft;
        var max = min + rangeBox.offsetWidth;
        if (event.clientX < min || event.clientX > max) return false;
    }
    else {
        var min = rect.top;
        var max = min + rangeBox.offsetHeight;
        if (event.clientY < min || event.clientY > max) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function updateProgress() {
    var current = player.currentTime;
    var percent = current / player.duration * 100;
    progress.style.width = percent + '%';
    currentTime.textContent = formatTime(current);
}

function updateVolume() {
    volumeProgress.style.height = player.volume * 100 + '%';
    if (player.volume >= 0.5) {
        speaker.attributes.d.value = 'M14.667 0v2.747c3.853 1.146 6.666 4.72 6.666 8.946 0 4.227-2.813 7.787-6.666 8.934v2.76C20 22.173 24 17.4 24 11.693 24 5.987 20 1.213 14.667 0zM18 11.693c0-2.36-1.333-4.386-3.333-5.373v10.707c2-.947 3.333-2.987 3.333-5.334zm-18-4v8h5.333L12 22.36V1.027L5.333 7.693H0z';
    }
    else if (player.volume < 0.5 && player.volume > 0.05) {
        speaker.attributes.d.value = 'M0 7.667v8h5.333L12 22.333V1L5.333 7.667M17.333 11.373C17.333 9.013 16 6.987 14 6v10.707c2-.947 3.333-2.987 3.333-5.334z';
    }
    else if (player.volume <= 0.05) {
        speaker.attributes.d.value = 'M0 7.667v8h5.333L12 22.333V1L5.333 7.667';
    }
}

function getRangeBox(event) {
    var rangeBox = event.target;
    var el = currentlyDragged;
    if (event.type == 'click' && isDraggable(event.target)) {
        rangeBox = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    }
    if (event.type == 'mousemove') {
        rangeBox = el.parentElement.parentElement;
    }
    return rangeBox;
}

function getCoefficient(event) {
    var slider = getRangeBox(event);
    var rect = slider.getBoundingClientRect();
    var K = 0;
    if (slider.dataset.direction == 'horizontal') {
        var offsetX = event.clientX - slider.offsetLeft;
        var width = slider.clientWidth;
        K = offsetX / width;
    }
    else if (slider.dataset.direction == 'vertical') {
        var height = slider.clientHeight;
        var offsetY = event.clientY - rect.top;
        K = 1 - offsetY / height;
    }
    return K;
}

function changeVolume(event) {
    if (inRange(event)) {
        player.volume = getCoefficient(event);
    }
}

function formatTime(time) {
    var min = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var sec = Math.floor(time % 60);
    return min + ':' + (sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec);
}

function togglePlay() {
    if (player.paused) {
        playPause.attributes.d.value = "M0 0h6v24H0zM12 0h6v24h-6z";
        player.play();
    }
    else {
        playPause.attributes.d.value = "M18 12L0 24V0";
        player.pause();
    }
}

function makePlay() {
    playpauseBtn.style.display = 'block';
    loading.style.display = 'none';
}

function directionAware() {
    if (window.innerHeight < 250) {
        volumeControls.style.bottom = '-54px';
        volumeControls.style.left = '54px';
    }
    else if (audioPlayer.offsetTop < 154) {
        volumeControls.style.bottom = '-164px';
        volumeControls.style.left = '-3px';
    }
    else {
        volumeControls.style.bottom = '52px';
        volumeControls.style.left = '-3px';
    }
}
```

Radio Player HTML:

```
                <div class="ggr-radio">
                    <div class="ggr-now-playing">
                        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2">
                            <span id="cc_strinfo_trackartist_gamersguildradio" class="cc_streaminfo"></span> - <span id="cc_strinfo_tracktitle_gamersguildradio" class="cc_streaminfo"></span>
                        </marquee>
                    </div>
                    <div class="audio ggr-radio-player">
                        <div class="loading">
                            <div class="spinner"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="play-pause-btn">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="24" viewBox="0 0 18 24">
                                <path fill="#566574" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0h6v24H0zM12 0h6v24h-6z" class="play-pause-icon" id="playPause" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <span class="current-time">0:00</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ggr-volume">
                            <div class="ggr-volume-btn">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path fill="#566574" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.667 0v2.747c3.853 1.146 6.666 4.72 6.666 8.946 0 4.227-2.813 7.787-6.666 8.934v2.76C20 22.173 24 17.4 24 11.693 24 5.987 20 1.213 14.667 0zM18 11.693c0-2.36-1.333-4.386-3.333-5.373v10.707c2-.947 3.333-2.987 3.333-5.334zm-18-4v8h5.333L12 22.36V1.027L5.333 7.693H0z" id="speaker"/>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ggr-volume-controls hidden">
                                <div class="ggr-slider" data-direction="vertical">
                                    <div class="ggr-progress">
                                        <div class="pin" id="ggr-volume-pin" data-method="changeVolume">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <audio crossorigin autoplay id="radio">
                            <source src="http://192.95.18.39:5272/stream" type="audio/mp3">
                        </audio>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is loading you setting the slider value everytime: player.volume = 0.25;

When the user changes the slider value or leave the current page, store the value it in a cookie.
When the page is refreshed, load the stored values from your cookie to the player.

Comment: Thank you, would this be a good starting point for using cookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp?

I ask because I have not used them before.

Comment: When you need to pass parameter from one page to second page you can use different technics: 1) sessions (server side), 2) pass parameter via url 3) cookies. Cookies are still accessible when the user leaves the page.

Comment: Okay, that should solve the volume issue then. Do you have any advice for making the radio player keep the music playing while changing pages? Right now every time someone changes to a new page the music pauses for a second while the page loads.

Comment: From where do you have the player?

Comment: On each page in the nav bar

Comment: The grr player opens a audio stream, does it? Every time you open a new webpage the stream will be buffered again. A simple solution for that: use iframes. Every sub page will be opened in the iframe of the main page. The player is part of the main page.